# Why is VSCode Dev Container extention not being able to build this container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vscode-extensions, vscode-devcontainer

I've been working in this project without trouble, everything was working fine till this morning.
My coworkers are running the same dev container and it works for them. We can´t seem to find what causes it not to build.
VSCode Dev Container extention fails to execute
`docker-compose -f /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/docker-compose-dev.yml config`

I've already

- Restarted VSCode
- Reinstalled dev container vscode extention
- Downgraded the extention
- Reinstalled docker
- Restarted my PC

The output log is the following:

```
[5271 ms] Dev Containers 0.299.0 in VS Code 1.82.2 (abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d).
[5270 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[5297 ms] 1.41
[5326 ms] Start: Run: /snap/code/140/usr/share/code/code --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4 --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --include-merged-configuration --mount-workspace-git-root true
[5573 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v18.15.0. linux 6.2.0-32-generic x64.
[5573 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4 --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[5593 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4
[5613 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[5702 ms] Docker Compose version: 
[5702 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose -f /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/docker-compose-dev.yml config
[5796 ms] 
[5796 ms] 
[5796 ms] Exit code 1
[5798 ms] Error: Command failed: docker-compose -f /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/docker-compose-dev.yml config
    at Dl (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2005:889)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async WN (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1935:23421)
    at async $ne (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:36212)
[5804 ms] Exit code 1
[1329962 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[1329993 ms] 1.41
[1330032 ms] Start: Run: /snap/code/140/usr/share/code/code --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js read-configuration --workspace-folder /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4 --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --include-merged-configuration --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 105 --terminal-rows 7
[1330292 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.46.0. Node.js v18.15.0. linux 6.2.0-32-generic x64.
[1330292 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4 --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
[1330314 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=/home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4
[1330335 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose version --short
[1330414 ms] Docker Compose version: 
[1330414 ms] Start: Run: docker-compose -f /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/docker-compose-dev.yml config
[1330495 ms] 
[1330495 ms] 
[1330495 ms] Exit code 1
[1330497 ms] Error: Command failed: docker-compose -f /home/oscar/reditec/sii-ci4/docker-compose-dev.yml config
    at Dl (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2005:889)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async WN (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1935:23421)
    at async $ne (/home/oscar/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.299.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:2156:36212)
[1330503 ms] Exit code 1
```

This is what is inside docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  correcaminos_dev:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.dev
    container_name: sii_dev
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - db_mysql_correcaminos_dev
      - db_mongo_correcaminos_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
      - ./config/php-dev/php:/usr/local/etc/php
    user: root

  db_mysql_correcaminos_dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.mysql
    container_name: mysqldb_dev
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=19630306
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sii_test
      - MYSQL_SSL_MODE=REQUIRED
    volumes:
      - data-db-test-mysql-correcaminos:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin_dev:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_dev
    ports:
      - "8443:443"
    links:
      - db_mysql_correcaminos_dev
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db_mysql_correcaminos_dev

  db_mongo_correcaminos_dev:
    image: mongo:7.0.1
    container_name: mongodb_dev
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=19630306
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=sii_test
    volumes:
      - data-db-test-mongo-correcaminos:/data/db

  mongo_express_dev: # Cliente web mongo
    image: mongo-express:1.0.0-alpha.4
    container_name: mongo_express_dev
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=db_mongo_correcaminos_dev
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=19630306
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=19630306
    links:
      - db_mongo_correcaminos_dev
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

  smtpserver_dev:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.1
    restart: always
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"  # Puerto para SMTP
      - "8025:8025"  # Puerto para interfaz web

volumes:
  data-db-test-mysql-correcaminos:
  data-db-test-mongo-correcaminos:
```

This is what is inside dockerfile.dev

```
FROM php:8.2.6-apache

# Actualizamos la lista de paquetes disponibles
RUN apt-get update

# Nos aseguramos de que el paquete esté disponible
RUN apt-get install --reinstall -y locales

# descomentamos la locale que vamos a utilizar
RUN sed -i 's/# es_MX.UTF-8 UTF-8/es_MX.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen

# Generamos la locale elegida
RUN locale-gen es_MX.UTF-8

# seteamos las environment variables
ENV LANG es_MX.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE es_MX
ENV LC_ALL es_MX.UTF-8

# Verificamos la configuración actualizada
RUN dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales


# Instalamos la biblioteca libzip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libzip-dev \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Intalamos las librearías de php que necesitaremos
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip \
    p7zip-full \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libonig-dev && docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN apt install -y libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

RUN apt install -y libxml2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install xml

RUN apt install -y libcurl3-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv

# Instalamos y configuramos una herramienta para enviar correos
# Instalar msmtp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y msmtp
# Configurar msmtp
RUN { \
    echo "defaults"; \
    echo "auth           on"; \
    echo "tls            on"; \
    echo "tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"; \
    echo "logfile        ~/.msmtp.log"; \
    echo "account        gmail"; \
    echo "host           smtp.gmail.com"; \
    echo "port           587"; \
    echo "from           ocotlan.tecnm@gmail.com"; \
    echo "user           ocotlan.tecnm@gmail.com"; \
    echo "password       idikrthhmieukihz"; \
    echo "account default : gmail"; \
} > /etc/msmtprc


# Creamos un certificado SSL 
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
   -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key \
   -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt \
   -subj "/C=MX/ST=Jalisco/L=Ocotlan/O=Instituto Tecnologico de Ocotlan/OU=SII/CN=localhost"

# Edita la configuración de Apache para habilitar SSL
RUN sed -i 's/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem/apache-selfsigned.crt/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf \
    && sed -i 's/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key/apache-selfsigned.key/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf \
    && a2ensite default-ssl.conf


# Instalamos composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

# Añadimos /usr/local/bin a la variable de entorno PATH
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin


# Instalamos node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Instalamos git
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Variables de entorno
ENV PATH="/var/www/html/vendor/bin/:${PATH}"

# Limpiamos la cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Habilitamos el modulo rewrite en la configuración de apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Habilita el módulo SSL
RUN a2enmod ssl


# Damos permisos de escritura en las carpetas
COPY ./scripts/start-script.sh /start-script.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix /start-script.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/start-script.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

# Reinicia Apache para aplicar los cambios
RUN apache2ctl restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 443
```

I've already

- Restarted VSCode
- Reinstalled dev container vscode extention
- Downgraded the extention
- Reinstalled docker
- Restarted my PC